# Передать значение рулетки в alert JS

Tags: javascript, html

возникла проблема, до решения которой не могу додуматься. Нашел исходники рулетки, которая случайным образом выбирает  из index.html и подкрашивает его после завершения анимации.

```html
<body>
    <div class="shadow"></div>
    <div class="random">
        <div class="result"></div>
        <div class="cards">
            <div id="cc">
                <img src="img\cc.png" style="width: 100px; height: 70px">
            </div>
            <div id="phone">
                <img src="img\phone.png" style="width: 100px; height: 70px">
            </div>
            <div id="tax">
                <img src="img\tax free.png" style="width: 100px; height: 70px">
            </div>
            <div id="viber">
                <img src="img\skype, viber.png" style="width: 100px; height: 70px">
            </div>
            <div id="netflix">
                <img src="img\netflix.png" style="width: 100px; height: 70px">
            </div>
            <div id="vk">
                <img src="img\vk kombo.png" style="width: 100px; height: 70px">
            </div>
            <div id="asos">
                <img src="img\asos.png" style="width: 100px; height: 70px">
            </div>
            <div id="tg">
                <img src="img\tg prem.png" style="width: 100px; height: 70px">
            </div>
            <div id="xbox">
                <img src="img\xbox.png" style="width: 100px; height: 70px">
            </div>
            <div id="twitch">
                <img src="img\twitch.png" style="width: 100px; height: 70px">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="start" onclick="start()">Участвовать</button>
    
    <script src="mine.js"></script>
</body>
```

Скрипт рулетки на JS:

```js
var cards_block = document.querySelector('.cards');
var cards = document.querySelectorAll('.cards > div');


function start() {
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10); // От 0 до 8
  cards_block.style.left = -random * 100 + 'px';
  setTimeout(function() {
    random++;
    cards[random].style.background = '#F5B036';
    cards[random].style.color = 'white';
  }, 5000)

}
```

Сам вопрос: как можно передать значение случайного , который был выигрышным?

К каждой позиции рулетки у меня будет массив строк, которые случайным образом должны отображаться во всплывающем окне

Comment: Вы не написали куда передать

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать функцию Math.random() для генерации случайного индекса в массиве. Затем используйте этот индекс для получения элемента из массива.

```
let arrPhone = ['+1 123 456 7890', '+1 987 654 3210', '+1 111 222 3333'];

let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * arrPhone.length);
let randomString = arrPhone[randomIndex];

alert(randomString);
```

Вы также можете использовать метод splice() для удаления элемента из массива, если вы не хотите, чтобы элемент использовался снова.